# A Problem for Nil-Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Consider a ring $R$ and $I$ be a finitely generated nil-ideal of $R$. Is $I$ a nilpotent ideal? I have proved this for commutative rings. But for non-commutative rings I think this may not be true. Can you help me?

Comment: There is a construction, due to Golod, of an algebra which has a finitely generated, nil, but not nilpotent ideal $I$. The key to showing that $I$ is not nilpotent is to show that it is infinite-dimensional. This depends on a theorem of Golod and Shafarevich. The algebra itself is realized as a quotient of a free algebra in two or more indeterminates. The ideal is the one generated by all the indeterminates. The construction is quite intricate. See P.M. Cohn, Basic Algebra, Exercise 5 in Section 6.3. Posting this as a comment because I do not give any details.

Comment: Can you send me the link of the article by Golod? @moonlight

Comment: The original reference is: Golod, E. S., _On nil-algebras and finitely approximable p-groups_. Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 28, 1964, 273–276. (It does not appear to be available online.) However, it is in Russian. It is MR0161878 on MathSciNet. You may be able to track down different constructions of nil but not nilpotent finitely generated algebras using that.

Comment: The article actually is online [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=2956&option_lang=eng). I don't read Russian, but based on the formulas I think Golod's construction is precisely the one sketched in Cohn's exercise. The exercise seems not hard: Only a few technical estimates have to be filled in, to ensure the Golod-Shafarevich theorem applies. Over countable base fields these technicalities can be avoided entirely: There is a very simple variant of the construction in Herstein's book *Noncommutative Rings*, Thm. 8.1.3.